# "Correct" way to mark up testimonials in HTML

Tags: html

I thought this would be an easy enough thing to find online but it seems not. I'm trying to find out what would be considered the correct way to mark up a list of testimonials - quotes with authors - on a page.

e.g.

> "This is what I think"
>   - My Name, My Company

I'd imagine the quote should go in a blockquote. I've also seen some use of cite to shown where a quote comes from but the HTML reference seems to show that this should be used to give the URL of a web page that the quote comes from, not the name of the person.

Does anyone have any suggestions for how this should be marked up?

Comment: When you refer to "cite", which are you referring to: the attribute for <blockquote> or the element?

Comment: I was referring to the element - didn't actually realise there was an attribute of the same name.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### The "old" way:

I might be chiming in **very** late, but I think the following is the correct way to mark up a testimonial:

```
<figure>
    <blockquote>
        "This is what I think"
    </blockquote>
    <footer>
        — <cite class="author">My Name</cite>, <cite class="company">My Company</cite>
    </footer>
</figure>
```

Per the W3C spec:

> ...the citation is contained within the footer of a figure element, this groups and associates the information, about the quote, with the quote...
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> The figure element represents some flow content, optionally with a caption, that is self-contained (like a complete sentence)...

### Update:

As @MCTaylor17 has pointed out, the best practice has changed in regards to citing a quote. Here's the new spec (as of December 2017): https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/textlevel-semantics.html#the-cite-element

Now the `<cite>` element is expected anywhere you would expect [Phrasing Content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/dom.html#phrasing-content-2). This means that it should go within a `<p>`, `<blockquote>`, etc.

Example 17 in the spec demonstrates using a `<cite>` within a `<blockquote>`:

```
  <blockquote>"Money is the real cause of poverty,"
  <footer>
  <cite id="baseref">The Ragged-Trousered Philanthropists, page 89.</cite>
  </footer>
  </blockquote>
```

To apply this to your own quote:

```
<blockquote>
    "This is what I think"
    <footer>
        — <cite class="author">My Name</cite>, <cite class="company">My Company</cite>
    </footer>
</blockquote>
```

Comment: I don't think this is best practice anymore.  From what I gather, it's best to put the `<footer>` inside the `<blockquote>` eliminating the need for a `<figure>`.

Comment: @MCTaylor17 I wouldn't be surprised if best practice has changed in the last 3 years :) I'll check the W3C spec and see if they've amended it. If so, I'll add an update to my post with the new recommendation.

Comment: This is worth reading as it probable is always up to date: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-blockquote-element

Answer (score 13):

You are correct in your assumption that a quote is supposed to go into a `blockquote` element and that the `cite` attribute should be used for the URI. Personally I handle the author of the quote with a separate `div` or `p` at the bottom of the quote like so:

```
<blockquote cite="http://a.uri.com/">
    <p>This is a really insightful sentence.</p>
    <p class="quoteCite">Darko Z</p>
</blockquote>
```

Then I just use CSS to make it look nice. Pretty basic. You might want to go look at [Microformats.org](http://microformats.org/) as well and search around for ideas.

Hope this helps

**EDIT:** Its late and it slipped my mind but you could also use the `cite` element

```
<blockquote cite="http://a.uri.com/">
    <p>This is a really insightful sentence.</p>
    <cite>Darko Z</cite>
</blockquote>
```

but im not a 100% sure how well its supported, to be honest

**EDIT 2:** According to the HTML 5 draft, [cite shoudn't be an author name](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-cite-element) so for future proofing you probably shouldn't use cite for that purpose.

Comment: The cite isn't part of the quote, it should be outside the blockquote element. Blockquote is for quoting block content, so you should wrap paragraph (for instance) elements around the content of them.

Comment: Agreed about wrapping content - have updated code. still not so certain about whether the cite should be a part of the quote or not (though thats the way i have done in the past). Looking for credible sources right now to see what they say...

Comment: Thanks for comments and suggestions. Microformats examples all seem to involve removing the blockquote element altogether; which seems a little strange.

I had a quick look through the HTML 5 draft. Handy that they say cite shouldn't be used for the author name then neglect to say what should be used for it.

So, probably going to use some mish-mash of blockquote, cite and microformats.

Thanks again,

K

Comment: RE: what element to use for names. From HTML 5 Working Draft, 23 April 2009: "In some cases, the b element might be appropriate for names; e.g. in a gossip article where the names of famous people are keywords rendered with a different style to draw attention to them. In other cases, if an element is really needed, the span element can be used."

Comment: 9 years later, and HTML 5.3 says the name _is part of the citation_.  http://w3c.github.io/html/textlevel-semantics.html#the-cite-element

Answer (score 10):

Things changed. I think a proper structure in this century should look like:

```
<blockquote>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
    <footer>
       <cite title="Source Title">
          <a href="http://www.thelorem.com">Bill Gates</a>
       </cite>
    </footer>
</blockquote>
```

Answer (score 6):

You may be interested in using the [hReview](http://microformats.org/wiki/hreview) format--Google is rumored to support it, and it's pretty much applicable to your situation, depending on whether you're only interested in the appearance, or whether you want to facilitate machine readability as well.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't think of using of using a review mf for a testimonial - great idea!

Answer (score 1):

Following the [Mozilla Developer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure#Quotations) this is the correct way to mark up a testimonial:

```
<figure>
    <blockquote>
        "This is my testimonial"
    </blockquote>
    <figcaption>
        — <cite class="author">My Name</cite>, <cite class="company">My Company</cite>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two solutions based on the [HTML Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/):

```
<blockquote>
 <p>This is what I think</p>
</blockquote>
<p>- My Name, My Company</p>
```

```
<figure>
 <blockquote>
  <p>This is what I think</p>
 </blockquote>
 <figcaption>My Name, My Company</figcaption>
</figure>
```

As [Darko Z. says in the edit of his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1130620/879628) you should not use `<cite>` for the author's name. This is because, according to [the spec today](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-cite-element), `<cite>` is for marking up the title of a work, not for naming the author. In [WHATWG](https://whatwg.org/)'s own words:

> The cite element represents the title of a work... A person's name is not the title of a work — even if people call that person a piece of work — and the element must therefore not be used to mark up people's names.

[The spec also says](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-blockquote-element), that "attribution for the quotation, if any, must be placed outside the blockquote element."

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how this should be marked up semantically, yes, use a block quote, and yes, the cite attribute is for URL's. As for presentation, you could use whatever you want and style it accordingly.

Visitors will never see the difference unless they look at the source code, and I can't imagine that it would affect SEO either.

Comment: The cite attribute is for URIs, not just URLs. You could, for instance, use an ISBN URN if you were quoting from a book.

Comment: I'm aware. I was using his terminology for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 includes a `<figcaption>` tag. To whit:

```
<figure>
    <blockquote cite="http://example.com/page">
        Nevermore
    </blockquote>
    <figcaption>
        The Raven
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Answer (score -1):

A lot of comments here suggesting to use the `cite` element for the name of the person who wrote the review.

> The `<cite>` HTML element is used to describe a reference to a cited creative work, and must include the title of that work.

[The Citation element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/cite)

Comment: It may be helpful to add an example to this.

Comment: @ethry The following example is from the link in my comment:

`<figure><blockquote><p>It was a bright cold day in April, and the clocks were striking thirteen.</p></blockquote><figcaption>First sentence in <cite><a href="http://www.george-orwell.org/1984/0.html">Nineteen Eighty-Four</a><cite> by George Orwell (Part 1, Chapter 1).</figcaption></figure>`

Answer (score -4):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<blockquote>
  <p>Quote
</blockquote>
<p>Author
```

would be the most correct.

Comment: You could at least add closing </p> tags. Might help remove the negative votes....

Comment: @RickDonohoe actually per the HTML5 spec: A p element's end tag can be omitted if the p element is immediately followed by an address, article, aside, blockquote, details, div, dl, fieldset, figcaption, figure, footer, form, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, header, hgroup, hr, main, menu, nav, ol, p, pre, section, table, or ul element, or if there is no more content in the parent element and the parent element